# ML.NET ImageClassification crash on macOS

Tags: c#, ml.net

I am about to figure out ML.NET and startet with an Microsoft Example which is linked down here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/image-classification-api-transfer-learning

I did everything as explained (creating assets-Dir and downloading files etc.) but when I run the Application I always run into a Problem that dotnet crashes away. I can't catch it with "try-catch".

My Code is:

```
var projectDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "../../../"));
        var workspaceRelativePath = Path.Combine(projectDirectory, "workspace");
        var assetsRelativePath = Path.Combine(projectDirectory, "assets");

        MLContext mlContext = new MLContext();

        IEnumerable<ImageData> images = LoadImagesFromDirectory(folder: assetsRelativePath, useFolderNameAsLabel: true);
        IDataView imageData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(images);
        IDataView shuffledData = mlContext.Data.ShuffleRows(imageData);

        var preprocessingPipeline = mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapValueToKey(
                inputColumnName: "Label",
                outputColumnName: "LabelAsKey")
            .Append(mlContext.Transforms.LoadRawImageBytes(
                outputColumnName: "Image",
                imageFolder: assetsRelativePath,
                inputColumnName: "ImagePath"));

        IDataView preProcessedData = preprocessingPipeline
                            .Fit(shuffledData)
                            .Transform(shuffledData);

        TrainTestData trainSplit = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(data: preProcessedData, testFraction: 0.3);
        TrainTestData validationTestSplit = mlContext.Data.TrainTestSplit(trainSplit.TestSet);

        IDataView trainSet = trainSplit.TrainSet;
        IDataView validationSet = validationTestSplit.TrainSet;
        IDataView testSet = validationTestSplit.TestSet;

        var classifierOptions = new ImageClassificationTrainer.Options()
        {
            FeatureColumnName = "Image",
            LabelColumnName = "LabelAsKey",
            ValidationSet = validationSet,
            Arch = ImageClassificationTrainer.Architecture.ResnetV2101,
            MetricsCallback = (metrics) => Console.WriteLine(metrics),
            TestOnTrainSet = false,
            ReuseTrainSetBottleneckCachedValues = true,
            ReuseValidationSetBottleneckCachedValues = true
        };

        var trainingPipeline = mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.ImageClassification(classifierOptions)
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));
```

As soon as I reach the last line:

```
mlContext.MulticlassClassification.Trainers.ImageClassification(classifierOptions)
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Conversion.MapKeyToValue("PredictedLabel"));
```

The App crash and I don't see any error. If I copy the same code onto my Windows-System it's working fine.

I am working with macOS Monterey on my MacBook Pro M1.
ML-Nuget-Packages are Installed in Version 1.6 with Tensorflow-Redist-Package-Version 2.3.1

Do you guys have any idea what's going on there or how can I troubleshoot it?

UPDATE (.csproj-File):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Microsoft.ML.Vision" />
    <None Remove="Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics" />
    <None Remove="Microsoft.ML" />
    <None Remove="SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.Vision" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.ImageAnalytics" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML" Version="1.6.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SciSharp.TensorFlow.Redist" Version="2.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**UPDATE**

with the newly released Visual Studio 2022 for Mac Version it's now possible to catch the Exception:

> Unable to load shared library 'tensorflow' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES environment variable: dlopen(libtensorflow, 0x0001): tried: 'libtensorflow' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libtensorflow' (no such file)

So obviously it cannot find the tensorflowlib. I will try to install the lib by myself now.

Comment: Pleae post the contents of your `.csproj` file

Comment: Are you compiling for x64 on both Windows and Linux? When using `string projectDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "../../../"));`,  if compiling for "Any CPU", you'll have `DeepLearning_ImageClassification_Binary\bin\Debug`, `DeepLearning_ImageClassification_Binary\assets`, and `DeepLearning_ImageClassification_Binary\workspace`. However, if you compile for x64, you'll have `DeepLearning_ImageClassification_Binary\bin\x64`, `DeepLearning_ImageClassification_Binary\bin\assets`, and `DeepLearning_ImageClassification_Binary\bin\workspace`

Comment: both, windows and macOS-Solutions are Build-Target "Any CPU" (default)

Comment: @JoeGER94 did you ever find a solution here?

Comment: @ChickenMilkBomb as far as I know the Problem should be fixed with .net5.
If you still run into the Problem with .net5 then contact me again and I will try it too. 
The Problem was that dotnet had a wrong path to the tensorflowlib. Before .net5 you had to configure something to get it work (there was also an Issue at Github, but dont know the Id anymore)